# Почему выводится 0?

Tags: c++

Где ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n, a, otv = 0;

    cin >> n;
    int arr[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            a = arr[i];
            if( sqrt(a) == 0 ) otv++;
    }
    cout << otv;
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Ответ выводится 0 =/

Comment: ну, если "a == 0", то otv будет не 0 :\  
если честно соовсем непонятная конструкция, вы таким образом нули в масиве ищите ? так а зачем sqrt ? или я чего то не понимаю ? что вы этим хотите получить ?

Comment: @lirik90 нет, моя задача найти в массиве числа, у которых есть корни. Поэтому я хочу щас извлечь корень, и если корень числа = 0, то ответ верный и ответ++. Но он выводит мне 0

Comment: Извините меня, но корень какого числа кроме 0 будет 0 ?

Comment: @lirik90 обновил код. Выложил весь. Смотри

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может как то так надо ???

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n, a, otv = 0;
    double b;

    cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[n];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
            a = arr[i];
            b = sqrt(a);
            if (b - int(b) == 0.0)
                otv++;
    }

    delete[] arr;
    cout << otv;

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: для double == использовать плохо.  Правильно fabs(b - int(b)) < EPSILON

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, плохо звучит здорово!!! Может пример приведете когда это будет работать не правильно ?!

Comment: @lirik90, одно число double практически гарантированно не будет в точности равно другому double, если конечно это не одно и то же число или если числа не получены в процессе одних и тех же вычислений.